# Однородные и неоднородные прилагательные. А не выпить ли нам старого доброго крепкого виски?

Tags: синтаксис, семантика

"А не выпить ли нам старого доброго крепкого виски?" Нужны ли здесь запятые?

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы. Я тоже думаю, что запятые здесь не нужны.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я здесь усматриваю ровно два неоднородных определения:

- крепкий - упоминание о свойствах (желаемых от напитка в данный момент)
- старый добрый - устойчивый символ чего-то хорошо проверенного ("старый в хорошем смысле"), можно трактовать это как эквивалент одного прилагательного

Поэтому как и в случае "крепкого индийского чаю", не надо запятых.

Answer (score 2):

Корректно без запятой, это неоднородные определения, характеризующее напиток с разных сторон: старый( временной признак),добрый( качественный).

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что в этом случае автор может рассчитывать на определенную степень свободы от жестких правил.

Признаки разные,  их можно сблизить, раскрывая тему хорошего виски, но можно и не сближать, если у автора нет на это желание. Да и структура предложения не располагает к перечислительной интонации.

Поэтому лучше остановиться на варианте без запятых: "А не выпить ли нам старого доброго крепкого виски?"

Answer (score 1):

По первому впечатлению определения выглядят как неоднородные, запятые не нужны. Но при этом, если автор будет настаивать на однородности (малореальный случай, но если ряд продолжить, то вопрос может встать), то придется поверить. Или попробуйте поменять порядок и/или значение в устойчивом сочетании. *"[история] старого крепкого доброго з**а**мка" - здесь неоднородность далеко не столь очевидна.

Answer (score 0):

Поставил бы одну, после **старого**, что б  следующий раз переход к четырём неоднородным не стал бы нелогичным.